# Binding a function directly vs a wrapper using jQuery. Why doesn't it work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, binding

My code:

```
var cardFrame = {
    element: "VALUE",
    flip: function(){
        console.log("flip: "+this.element);
    },
};
```

When button is bound with this line, clicking it prints `flip: VALUE` as it should.

```
$("#flashcard").bind( "click", function(){cardFrame.flip();} );
```

If bound with the line below.  The button prints`flip: undefined`

```
$("#flashcard").bind( "click", cardFrame.flip );
```

These two statements should be functionally equal.  Why is this?

Comment: `bind` is deprecated.  You should use the `on` event handler.  `bind` calls this behind the scenes anyway.   `$('#flashcard').on('click', cardFrame.flip);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not equal, "this" is different in the two circumstances.

Int the first, "flip" is called as a method of "cardFrame", so in the function "this" is the object "cardFrame".

In the 2nd, "this" which is passed by jQuery is the element which you attached click event to.

You can read the [reference about this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is the different scope (value of this).

in the first case the value of this points to the object cardFrame as you want.

In the second case this points to the #flashcard element because it is used directly in the event.

To understand what is going on do:

```
var cardFrame = {
    element: "VALUE",
    flip: function(){
        console.log(this);
    },
};
```

you will see that the value is different in the two cases.